# Code works in Excel 2010 but not in Office (Excel) 365, what was changed?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple code which updates cell `F` with current date and time whenever something was modified.

Tried it again on Excel 2010 and it has no issue.

I tried commenting out the `.NumberFormat` line and it worked before but it no longer works now.

```
If Target.Row < 6 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

With Me.Cells(Target.Row, "F")
    .Value = CDbl(Now)
    .NumberFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss"
End With
```

It's supposed to update the cell with current date and time but now it does nothing and makes Excel unresponsive. I need to force-close it to be able to work on the file again.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything there which would be a problem on Excel/Office 365.  Maybe if you could post a full testable procedure?  Is this being used in an event handler?

Comment: could it be a reference problem?

Comment: Are you disabling events before updating the sheet in the event handler?

Comment: Disabling the events first solved the issue. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Target` variable I guess you are handling events. But your code raises also events, which you probably handle, which results in event loop, each calling you event handler again and again. You need to turn off events for time when macro runs:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row < 6 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' turn off events
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Me.Cells(Target.Row, "F")
        .Value = CDbl(Now)
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss"
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
If Selection.Row < 6 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

With ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, 6)
    .Value = Now
    .NumberFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss"
End With
```

I am assuming that you are in the active sheet as you did not expose the declaration of Me and Target. If not, just custom it.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this problems before. Try this

```
If Selection.Row > 6 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, 6) = Format(now,"yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss")
```